# Skeptics Podcast - Ep. 2 is out!

Tags: discussion, podcast

[image: logo]

In this episode:

- The moon and its myths and legends
- Hot questions
- Top users

You can download from or listen at [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/user9210836/skeptics-stack-exchange-podcast-s01-e02), or follow on [TuneIn](http://tunein.com/radio/Skeptics-Stack-Exchange-Podcast-p869154/). A podcast [RSS feed](http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:2636145/sounds.rss) is also available.

Answer (score 4):

My podcast player finally put the Skeptics Podcast at the top of the list, and I got to hear them.

I really enjoyed the first two shows.

Part of the joy was getting to hear what Sklivvz and Larian sound like. (Larian sounded much younger than I guessed, and Sklivvz sounded very different than I imagined. After a bit of introspection, I think I have been imagining him with a Spanish accent instead of an Italian one, which is very weird.)

I like the shout-out section to the top and upcoming users. I have been listening to that and thinking "Yeah, that was an excellent first post by so-and-so."

I found the background music in the first one distracting, but that was fixed in the second one, so yay!

Perhaps these meta-posts could be used as show notes, linking to the questions and users mentioned in the show?